# How to make a link change the content of a paragraph on click? return false not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am learning to code JavaScript. In this script, I want a link to not go to its specified location, but to change the text in the paragraph before it. I have created a function to achieve it `onclick`, but the function is not able to return false.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Test #6</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("links").onclick=writeData();
        function writeData()
            {
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Changed Paragraph Content";
                return false;
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para">Unchanged Paragraph Content</p>
    <br/>
    <a id="links" href="javascript-return.html"> Click here to change the paragraph content </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("links").onclick=writeData;
```

Don't use the brackets. They force your function to evaluate. but you want to assign the function.

EDIT:

Of Course, you need to Assign your Function after the Document has been loaded. The way it is right now, there will be no element with id `links` when the assignment is executed. Basically, just put your script block below the `links` element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Test #6</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para">Unchanged Paragraph Content</p>
    <br/>
    <a id="links" href="javascript-return.html"> Click here to change the paragraph content </a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("links").onclick=writeData;
        function writeData()
        {
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Changed Paragraph Content";
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT (Using window.onload):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Test #6</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("links").onclick=writeData;
        }

        function writeData()
        {
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Changed Paragraph Content";
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="para">Unchanged Paragraph Content</p>
    <br/>
    <a id="links" href="javascript-return.html"> Click here to change the paragraph content </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried that, even that doesn't work. It still goes to the link on click.

Comment: Please have a look at my Edit, might do the trick. You could also have a look at how to use the `document ready` event, if you want to keep your scripts in the head section, just google for `javascript document ready event`

Comment: I tried assigning the function the way you mentioned (actually used the exact code). Didn't work. I am afraid it caused more problems. By default, the paragraph read "Changed Paragraph Content" instead of "Unchanged Paragraph Content"

Comment: And @Chips_100 is document ready a jQuery event? The search results are mostly some jQuery articles. I still haven't gotten to jQuery.     Sorry if I sound noobish, I have absolutely no idea other than what I've learnt so far.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my code - I copied your code and forgot to remove the brackets again. Try again without brackets (i also edited the code, so you can use it now). About the event: document ready is a `jQuery event` which basically just is a wrapper around `window.onload`. you might google for that term if you're not familiar with jQuery yet.

Comment: I know about window.onload. I've used it before to call functions. This issue is solved your way, but would be great if you could tell how window.onload is going to help here

Comment: Look at my latest Edit. You might use that code. Basically, you are just assigning a function to `window.onload` in which you are assigning the handler. That way, the assignment is executed when the DOM Elements have been loaded and so the element `links` is already loaded.

Comment: Oh wow Chips_100 Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot, you did more than solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with document.getElementById, you should ensure that at the time of the call, the elements are in DOM.
Just use an inline click handler:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Javascript Test #6</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function writeData()
        {
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Changed Paragraph Content";
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="para">Unchanged Paragraph Content</p>
        <br/>
        <a id="links" href="javascript-return.html" onclick="return writeData();">    Click here       to change the paragraph content </a>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Or, change the order of things: first have the DOM ready, and after that , insert you js script:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Javascript Test #6</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="para">Unchanged Paragraph Content</p>
        <br/>
        <a id="links" href="javascript-return.html" onclick="return writeData();">    Click here       to change the paragraph content </a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("links").onclick=writeData;
            function writeData()
            {
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Changed Paragraph Content";
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

see [it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/2CpcF/](http://jsfiddle.net/2CpcF/)

Comment: I have actually tried the first method before trying this out. But felt that it may be uncomfortable to call JS functions in the HTML body (when coding considerably longer pages). The main intention is to hide the JS from body (I am going to use an external JS file and try after this). Just curious, is this the general practice? Though the second method solves the purpose for now, it is not practical to write JS codes in the HTML body right?